# How do I get All the mesages from the SQS queue

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, aws-java-sdk

I am using SQS to read the data. But I am not sure how to read all the data from the queue.

```
public List<Customer> getMessage() {


 int numberOfMessages= getMessageCount();
 System.out.println(numberOfMessages);
 int count=0;
 while(count<10) {

     System.out.println("Messages remaining in the queue- 
 >>>"+numberOfMessages);
     System.out.println("Recieving Messages from the Queue: ");
        final ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest =
        new ReceiveMessageRequest(queueURL)
        .withMaxNumberOfMessages(10)
        .withWaitTimeSeconds(20);

        final List<com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.Message> customers =   
                  sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();


        for(com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.Message cust: customers) {
            System.out.println("Current message number->>>>>"+(count+1));
            System.out.println(cust.getBody());
            sqs.deleteMessage(new DeleteMessageRequest(queueURL,
                    cust.getReceiptHandle()));
            count++;
        }

        //numberOfMessages=getMessageCount();

 }
 return null;

 }

public int getMessageCount() {
    Set<String> attrs = new HashSet<String>();
     attrs.add("ApproximateNumberOfMessages");
     CreateQueueRequest createQueueRequest = new CreateQueueRequest().withQueueName("sampleQueueSharma");
     GetQueueAttributesRequest a = new GetQueueAttributesRequest().withQueueUrl(sqs.createQueue(createQueueRequest).getQueueUrl()).withAttributeNames(attrs);
     Map<String,String> result = sqs.getQueueAttributes(a).getAttributes();
     int num = Integer.parseInt(result.get("ApproximateNumberOfMessages"));
     return num;
    }
```

I am reading the data this way, but this doesnt seem right.

I also tried replacing `while(count<10)` with `while(numberOfMessages>0)` and uncommenting `numberOfMessages=getMessageCount()` this line , but by doing this, the code runs indefinitely. It seems like it always returns a 
value greater than 1.

Can someone help me with this thing?

Comment: Your program does not appear to be doing anything with the content of the messages — it is just deleting content. Is this intentional? What are you actually trying to accomplish with the code? If you just want to empty an existing queue, it's easiest to simply use [PurgeQueue()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_PurgeQueue.html) or empty the queue via the console.

Comment: Hey @JohnRotenstein. Actually, I want to create a Lambda function out of it which will take the data from sqs and send it to a rest service. For time being, I am just trying to get the data from the sqs and print it.

Answer (score 0):

First a few notes:

1. Using `count` as you are, you're only reading about 10 messages (may be slightly more due to batching). You probably don't want to use this beyond simple proof-of-concept stage
2. Using `while (numberOfMessages > 0)`, you're going to keep reading as long as SQS's approximation of the message count says it has messages. Note that this is an approximation, so you shouldn't rely on it being exact (it will be eventually consistent).
3. Your `getMessageCount()` method looks like it's trying to recreate the queue each time it's called - while that'll work, you don't need to do this. Create it once and just use it.

Based on the code I can see, `getMessageCount()` would return `> 1` if (a) you simply have a ton of messages, (b) something else is constantly adding messages to the queue (or (c) if you're not properly deleting them, but you are doing this).

I would suggest the following modifications to your code:

1. Log the result of `getMessageCount()` each time it's called. This will give you indication if you are putting messages into your queue faster than you can process them, or have some message source that will never run out.
2. Log the number of messages received by your `ReceiveMessageRequest`. This will let you know you are indeed processing messages.
3. Instead of basing your control flow on the value of `getMessageCount()`, keep calling until `ReceiveMessageRequest` result (with waitTimeSeconds=20) returns 0 messages - this is the guarantee that your queue is empty at that moment (instead of an approximation).

Answer (score 0):

Used ListIterator on messages

```
 List<com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.Message> messages = amazonSQS.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
        ListIterator<Message> messageListIterator = messages.listIterator();
        List<String> message=new ArrayList<>();


        while (messageListIterator.hasNext()){
           Message msg= messageListIterator.next();
            message.add(msg.getBody());
        }
```